# Angularjs AOT compilation ngfactory not found?

Tags: angularjs, angular2-aot

I am following https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler#compile to study AOT compilation in angularjs. AOT compilation is successfull but I am not able to access my app in browser. Its showing the following error:-

localhost/:18 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:3006/aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory
from http://localhost:3006/main.js

It is not able to find app.module.ngfactory, but its there in the aot generated directory.

main.ts file

```
import { platformBrowser }    from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppModuleNgFactory } from 
'../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory';

platformBrowser().bootstrapModuleFactory(AppModuleNgFactory);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you use angular-cli? 
If you have, use :  `ng serve --aot/ ng build --aot` to run your code.
That's convenient

Comment: thanks for reply, I used it, now CLI do aot by default in prod build.